# Fedora Werewolf - offline yum updates

Tags: linux, fedora, yum

I have an off-network machine that is running Fedora 8 Werewolf with kernel 2.6.22.18 and I need to get Linux headers installed on it. How do I do this when the machine can not be hooked to the network?

I do not have another Fedora machine that is on a network that I could use. However, I do have an Ubuntu 9.04 I could use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for those interested the headers are in the source code of the kernel. There is a headers folder.

This may be old news to many people but for me coming in as new to linux it was not very obvious where to get the headers.